# How do I vertically align my links for a navbar?

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I am trying to make a navigation bar but I'm not sure how to line up the `li` and `a` tags vertically. How can I do this?

```css
#navbar {
    font-weight: bold;
    display: block;
    background-color: #000;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #000;
}

li a {
    color: white;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
    background-color: #111;
}
```

```html
<div id="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li><img src="img/logo.png" width="75" height="75"></li>
            <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">MY WORK</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">HIRE ME</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">PROJECTS</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vertical align middle not working with ul li](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45712309/vertical-align-middle-not-working-with-ul-li)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the common ways nowadays is to do it with the ***Flexbox***:

```css
#navbar {
  font-weight: bold;
  display: block;
  background-color: #000;
}

ul {
  display: flex; /* displays flex-items (children) inline */
  align-items: center; /* centers them vertically */
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #000;
}

li {
  float: left;
}

li a {
  color: white;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: #111;
}

/* addition */
img {display: block} /* or: "vertical-align: middle" // removes bottom margin/whitespace */
```

```html
<div id="navbar">
  <ul>
    <li><img src="https://placehold.it/100x100" alt="" width="75" height="75"></li>
    <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">MY WORK</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">HIRE ME</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">PROJECTS</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```